# How to pass extra data to fastapi APIRouter?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn, asgi

This is my 1st fastapi exercise. I've my old model serving code implemented with Flask as following:

```python
class HealthCheck(Resource):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HealthCheck, self).__init__()
        self._model  = kwargs['model']
        self._logger = kwargs['logger']

    def get(self):
        if self._model:
            return {"status" : "healthy"}, HTTPStatus.OK
        return {"status": "unavailable"}, HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST

    def put(self):
        raise MethodNotAllowed('PUT request not supported')

    # similarly other methods are disabled

# In a different module, say in App class
        
class App():
    def __init__(self, name, logger, config):
        self._logger = logger
        self._model  = load_model(config['model_path'])
        self._flask_app = Flask(name)
        api = Api(self._flask_app)

        # logger and model is passed to HealthCheck resource
        api.add_resource(HealthCheck, "/api/healthcheck", 
                         resource_class_kwargs={'model': self._model, 'logger': self._logger})
```

How do I achieve same with fastapi APIRouter?
My example fastapi implementation is following:

```python
class HealthResult(BaseModel):
    healthy: bool

health_router = fastapi.APIRouter()

@health_router.get("/healthcheck", response_model=HealthResult, name="heathcheck")
async def heartbeat() -> HealthResult:
    hb = HealthResult(healthy=True)
    return hb

# in the App module
class App():
    def __init__(self, name, logger, config):
        self._logger = logger
        self._model  = load_model(config['model_path'])
        self._api = fastapi.FastAPI(title=name)
        self._api.include_router(health_router, prefix="/api")

        # how do I pass model and logger to health_router to use that in heartbeat method?
```

I want to avoid using any global storage for model and logger and access in health_router from there.

Also, since my fastapi object is inside App class, how can I invoke multiple worker with uvicorn in this case?

Comment: It seems the expression ***`class App(name, logger, config)`*** is not correct, in Python

Comment: @JPG - Thanks for pointing out. In the small edit window, I lost track of this typo.

Answer (score 2):

```
from fastapi import Request

app = FastAPI()
app.share_text = 'aaa'
    
# in Apirouter
@router.get("/share}", request: Request)
async def read( request: Request):
    #retrieve from app context
    share_text = request.app.share_text
    return {}
```

You could retrive the app context from `Request`

Ref: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#use-the-request-object-directly

Ref: https://www.starlette.io/requests/

> Application The originating Starlette application can be accessed via
> request.app.
>
> Other state If you want to store additional information on the request
> you can do so using request.state.
>
> For example:
>
> request.state.time_started = time.time()

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't like it, I modified my `App` class as following to get around the problem - still looking for cleaner solution.

```python
class App(metaclass=Singleton):
    _MODEL: Union[None, Model] = None
    _LOGGER: Union[None, CustomLogger] = None

    @classmethod
    def setLogger(cls, logger: CustomLogger) -> None:
        cls._LOGGER = logger

    @classmethod
    def getLogger(cls) -> CustomLogger:
        return cls._LOGGER

    @classmethod
    def setModel(cls, model: Model) -> None:
        assert model
        cls._MODEL = model

    @classmethod
    def getModel(cls) -> Model:
        return cls._MODEL

    def __init__(self, name: str, logger: CustomLogger, config: YAML) -> None:
        App.setLogger(logger)
        model: Model = load_model(config['model_path'])
        App.setModel(model)
        self._api = fastapi.FastAPI(title=name)
        self._api.include_router(health_router, prefix="/api")
        ....
```

```python
class HealthResult(BaseModel):
    healthy: bool

health_router = fastapi.APIRouter()

@health_router.get("/healthcheck", response_model=HealthResult, name="heathcheck")
async def heartbeat() -> HealthResult:
    model: Model = App.getModel()
    hb: HealthResult = HealthResult(healthy=True) if model else HealthResult(healthy=False)
    return hb
```